# CUDA boolean variable for host loop

Tags: c++, c, cuda

A very simplified version of my code looks like:

```
do {
    //reset loop variable b to 0/false
    b = 0;

    // execute kernel
    kernel<<<...>>>(b);

   // use the value of b for while condition
} while(b);
```

Boolean variable `b` can be set to `true` by any thread in `kernel` and it tells us whether we continue running our loop.

Using `cudaMalloc`, `cudaMemset`, and `cudaMemcpy` we can create/set/copy `device` memory to implement this. However I just found the existence of pinned memory. Using `cudaMalloHost` to allocate `b` and a call to `cudaDeviceSynchronize` right after the kernel gave quite a speed up (~50%) in a simple test program.

Is pinned memory the best option for this boolean variable `b` or is there a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown your initial code and the *modified* code therefore nobody can have any idea about the details of the improvement you are stating in your post.

The answer to your question varies depending on

1. The **b** is read and written or is only written inside the GPU kernel. Reads might need to fetch the actual value directly from the host side if **b** is not found in the cache resulting in latencies. On the other hand, the latency for writes can be covered if there are further operations that can keep the threads busy.
2. How frequent you modify the value. If you access the value frequently in your program, the GPU probably can keep the variable inside L2 avoiding host side accesses.
3. The frequency of memory operations between accesses to **b**. If there are many memory transactions between accesses to **b**, it is more probable that **b** in the cache is replaced with some other content. As a result, when accessed again, **b** could not be found in the cache and a time-consuming host-access is necessary.

In cases having **b** in the host side causes many host memory transactions, it is logical to keep it inside the GPU global memory and transfer it back at the end of each loop iteration. You can do it rather fast with an asynchronous copy in the same stream as kernel's and synchronize with the host right after.

All above items are for cache-enabled devices. If your device is pr-Fermi (CC<2.0), the story is different.